# Deleting a node from an arrayList<String> presentation

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a problem where I need to implement the delete method of a BST. The arrayList is in level order traversal that includes all the nodes even the null(s).
For example

```
    toBSTArray = [20,3,2] -> BSTArray<String> = ["20","3","null","2","null","null","null"]
```

This is what I got so far

```
        public void deleteFromStr(ArrayList<String> arr, String delVal){
        int i = 0;
        int leftChild, rightChild, parent;
        String node,leftChildStr,rightChildStr,parentString;
        while(!(arr.get(i).equals(delVal))){
            i++;
        }
        node = arr.get(i);
        leftChild =(2*i + 1);
        rightChild= (2 * i + 2);
        parent = (i - 1)/2;
        leftChildStr = arr.get(leftChild);
        rightChildStr = arr.get(rightChild);
        parentString = arr.get(parent);
        if(leftChildStr.equals("null") && rightChildStr.equals("null"))
            arr.remove(i);
    }
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is homework, I presume?

Comment: public void deleteFromStr(ArrayList<String> arr, String delVal){
        int i = 0;
        int leftChild = (2*i + 1), rightChild= (2 * i + 2), parent = (i - 1)/2;
        String node,leftChildStr,rightChildStr,parentString;
        while(!(arr.get(i).equals(delVal))){
            i++;
        }
        node = arr.get(i);
        leftChildStr = arr.get(leftChild);
        rightChildStr = arr.get(rightChild);
        parentString = arr.get(parent);
        if(leftChildStr.equals("null") && rightChildStr.equals("null"))
            arr.remove(i);
    }

Comment: Might be irrelevant, but updating `i` _won’t_ update `leftChild`, `rightChild` or `parent`. They are computed at assignment time, not stored as the formula you enter them as.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it already

Comment: Why are you doing a sequential search to locate the string?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. you have a direct-indexing representation, you can not actually remove nodes from the middle of the list, you can only set them to `"null"` (I would rather consider using `null`, by the way)
2. in a binary search tree (regardless of its representation) node removal has multiple cases depending on its children

If there are no children, you can just remove the node (`null` it). This part is there in your code, just it should not be `remove()`:

```
if(leftChildStr.equals("null") && rightChildStr.equals("null"))
    arr.set(i,"null"); // instead of arr.remove(i);
```

If one child is `null`, the other one has to be moved upwards with its entire subtree.
I could imagine a recursive helper function for that:

```
void moveup(ArrayList<String> arr,int from,int to){
    if(from>=arr.size()){
        arr.set(to,"null");
        return;
    }
    String nodeString=arr.get(from);
    arr.set(to,nodeString);
    if(!nodeString.equals("null")){
        moveup(arr,from*2+1,to*2+1);
        moveup(arr,from*2+2,to*2+2);
    }
}
```

(It's `moveup` because it does not check for `to` being too large and does not attempt to extend the list)
Then the cases (continuing the `if` from above):

```
else if(leftChildStr.equals("null"))
    moveup(arr,rightChild,i);
else if(rightChildStr.equals("null"))
    moveup(arr,leftChild,i);
```

And there is a final `else` for handling the presence of both left and right children. That is a tricky one, in fact I do not wish to think about it, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion) has some idea:

> Deleting a node with two children: call the node to be deleted D. Do not delete D. Instead, choose either its in-order predecessor node or its in-order successor node as replacement node E (s. figure). Copy the user values of E to D.[note 2] If E does not have a child simply remove E from its previous parent G. If E has a child, say F, it is a right child. Replace E with F at E's parent.

Coupled with an illustration:

[image]

First of all, implementing this idea would require actual navigation in the tree, and as a comment points out right now the question shows sequential search in the list instead of a binary search.